# IOS: Subclassing view loaded from NIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, subclass, nib

I have created nib with custom tableViewCell.
Created Class TableViewCellSimple for it with black label color.

Now I want to subclass this cell and get red color of label.
So, I create subclass of it TableViewCellRedColor and override init method.

```
- (void)setup
{
     [super setup];
     self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor k_mainRed];
}
```

In my VC, I register this 2 cells:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewCellSimple" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier_ TableViewCellSimple];
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewCellRedColor" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier_ TableViewCellRedColor];
```

And then I creating cells:

```
  switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
            {
                TableViewCellSimple *cell = (TableViewCellSimple *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier_ TableViewCellSimple];
                cell.titleLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Clear All Messages", nil);
                return cell;
            }
                break;

            case 1:
            {
                TableViewCellRedColor *cell = (TableViewCellRedColor *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier_ TableViewCellRedColor];
                cell.titleLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Leave Chat and Event", nil);
                return cell;
            }
                break;
```

But I did not get red color. I debug my code and overridden method did not called.

Why?

Comment: where did you call `[self setup]` in `TableViewCellRedColor`? If it's not in `- (void)awakeFromNib` , try putting it there

Comment: @BenJammin,  yes from it, awakeFromNib did no called too

Comment: It looks to me (from your code) that you have a nib file for this subclass, tableViewCellRedColor.. So why not just set the text colour there?  Is the cell in that second nib set to the red subclass in the identity inspector? I think you ought class test some cells and confirm that they are in fact instances of the correct subclasses as you intend. Good luck